# Unable to access group address for template in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I'm trying to enumerate my `eth0` address (set to default, because I read somewhere that eth0 is not always available..). In my template I attempt calling it from the group like so...

```
[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes Kube Proxy
Documentation=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kube-proxy \
  --master=https://{{ groups[controller][0]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}:6443 \
  --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig \
  --proxy-mode=iptables \
  --v=2

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This seem like it should be available as when I dump with `-debug var=groups` I get....

```
[18.234.92.196] => {
    "groups": {

      ......

        "controller": [
            "54.86.253.135",
            "52.205.43.24",
            "54.210.213.10"
        ],
        "controller.0": [
            "54.86.253.135"
        ],
        "controller.1": [
            "52.205.43.24"
        ],
        "controller.2": [
            "54.210.213.10"
        ],

        ......

        "name_controller-0": [
            "54.86.253.135"
        ],
        "name_controller-1": [
            "52.205.43.24"
        ],
        "name_controller-2": [
            "54.210.213.10"
        ],

        ......

    }
}
```

Weirdly when I try debugging with `var=groups[controller]` I get ...

```
TASK [worker : debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [34.207.172.100] => {
    "groups[controller]": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'controller' is undefined"
}

.....

TASK [worker : Add Kubelet configuration] ***********************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [34.207.172.100]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'controller' is undefined"}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, needed to specify the IP via groups first and use that as an index.

Also, `ansible_default_ipv4` does not seem to exist, so swapped to `public_ip` which is the same thing.

```
- name: Print hostvars
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars[groups.controller.0].public_ip }}"
```